# How many repositories should I have in my Android App using Room?

Tags: android, repository, android-room

According to the official Google Documentation on the new Architecture Components for Android, using Room for saving data into an SQL Database requires a class to be used as a Repository.

This example illustrates a little bit:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#7

But the example only works with a table with 2 columns and it's not clear if I should be doing either:

1. Create 1 repository to implement all of the app DAO's
2. Create 1 repository for each DAO
3. Create 1 repository per Activity
4. Other?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd go with 2. Create a repository for each DAO.

Comment: Just to make sure, The repositories are not Singletons and i use multiple sets of data in each activity.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple sets of data in each activity? The repositories need not be singletons because your retrofit and room db objects will singletons. Repository class is just a wrapper on top of both your network and db layer

Comment: For example, In "ActivityA" I need a set of lets say "Products" and another set of "Sales". "In ActivityB" Im also using a set of "Products" and a set of "Categories". Those are DAOS

Comment: It doesn't matter in how many places you're using "products". Because all of those products will come from the same table and will be queried from the same repository class. I'd suggest, not using a repository class at all if it seems confusing. Just create a single for your room db and query from it